# Backbone.js wait until callback before rendering

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

In the below code block I need to make sure `initialize1` and `initialize2` calls to the `remoteAPIObj` are both finished before rendering my view. Both functions are doing AJAX queries and execute the given callback functions.

So I have defined another function `renderOnce` and used underscore.js function `after` to make sure `renderOnce` is actually called 2 times before actually being executed. Is there anything missing in this approach? Or do you have any other suggestion?

```
window.MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#right-container'),
    render: function(eventName) {
        var template = Handlebars.compile($("#right-template").html());
        $(this.el).html(template(remoteAPIObj.getData()));

        return this;
    },
    initialize: _.once(function() {
        var self = this;
        remoteAPIObj.initialize1(function(){self.renderOnce();});
        remoteAPIObj.initialize2(function(){self.renderOnce();});
    }),
    renderOnce: _.after(2, function() {
        this.render();
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal way to do this with a jQuery promises approach - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Example :

```
$.when( $.ajax("test.aspx") ).then(function(ajaxArgs){ 
     alert(ajaxArgs[1]); /* ajaxArgs is [ "success", statusText, jqXHR ] */
});
```

If your internal code can be adapted to promises, you can do something like this

```
$.when(remoteAPIObj.initialize1, remoteAPIObj.initialize2).then(function(args1, args2){
    this.render();
});
```

Failing that, you can also use the event system to trigger an event that notifies the render method that the data is available. But this won't be terribly different than what you are already doing.

Comment: I think $.when will not wait until both of the callbacks of initialize1 and 2 are executed so I will have to make operations inside them synchronous in order to make it work

Comment: If you make it a deferred object I'm pretty sure that it will wait for both. Easy enough to try it out with some test ajax code.

Comment: Using return $.ajax({...}) inside initialize1 and initialize2 actually made $.when work